# User rights to read/write win.ini in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator, uac, elevated

I use a program in Windows 8.1 Pro that needs full read/write rights to win.ini.
- Logged in as administrator
- UAC is disabled
- Applications and administrators have full rights to modify win.ini. Nevertheless I cannot modify the file unless I run the program (or notepad) as administrator. This is however not an option for this application.

Anybody an idea which security setting I can change to accomplish this?

Art.

Comment: Did you disable UAC in the Registry or with Group Policy? The UAC slider bottom position does not disable UAC in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the program as administrator?

Right click on the icon and select "run as administrator" from the context menu.

I'm curious.  What program needs to write to win.ini in this day and age and why?

Comment: "Nevertheless I cannot modify the file unless I run the program (or notepad) as administrator. This is however not an option for this application." he can't run that application as an admin.

Comment: Actually I can run the program as administrator, but this is not the way to go since this will interfere with the companies security policy. And what program, well don't go there either. If I had a choice here.....

Comment: Well, after starting up again it suddenly worked. Looks more like a issue in Windows where disabling UAC was not properly applied.